# PHP Insert into £ symbol into table is display Â£

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting submitted data into a table.

Here is the echoed SQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO adhocbills_lineitems (bill_seq, unitprice, quantity, sagenominalcode, description) values ('119', '10', '1', '4000', 'test product for £ pounds')
```

but when i look in the database, it says `test product for Â£ pounds`

how can i get rid of the `Â` character when inserting?

Comment: Check the collation of your database and match the encoding of your php source file.

Comment: Make sure your tables, database connection and PHP-files use the same encoding

Comment: the description column is longtext ?? is this what you mean

Comment: the Collation of the description column is latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: And what is your php source file encoding? It's difficult to tell you the correct answer not knowing all the environment you are using, but it is probably due to an encoding problem. Try to *play* with your source file encoding...

Comment: where do i find the encoding for the source file?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you must check the Collation. You can use `latin1-bin`. To match php encoding you can use :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=latin1-bin');
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use utf-8 to support any character. You may fix this for latin1, but at some point you will have problem with other characters.  Change your table collation to utf8. And make sure your php file has:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```